# Custom spring-kafka deserializer for LocalDateTime

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm building a simple project with spring boot and spring-kafka, I can't configure it in order to make it work, it's a simple application that generates notes(author, content, createddatetime, lastmodifieddatetime) and sends events based on the notes when they are created.

I have been playing with it with 2 days but I guess I'm not getting it.

Here is my configuration, I'm pretty sure it has a lot of boiler plate but I've been using several examples to make mine work.

I have 2 producer and consumer factories because I need a default one, is that true? Do I need to create a custom factory for each type of message I am willing to send?

My application.yml

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/notes
spring.datasource.username: root
spring.datasource.password:

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL: debug

spring.jpa.database:  MYSQL
spring.jpa.open-in-view: true
spring.jpa.show-sql:  true
spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode: default

spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update

logging.level.org.springframework: DEBUG
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers: 192.168.169.22:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id: noteGroup
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset: earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages: com.remusrd.notesample.domain.event
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.add.type.headers: true
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

My producer

```
package com.remusrd.notesample.service

import arrow.core.Option
import arrow.core.getOrElse
import arrow.data.NonEmptyList
import com.remusrd.notesample.data.NoteRepository
import com.remusrd.notesample.domain.Note
import com.remusrd.notesample.domain.event.NoteEvent
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional


@Service
@Transactional
class JpaNoteService : NoteService {
    val TOPIC_NAME = "notes"

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var noteRepository: NoteRepository
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<String, NoteEvent>

    override fun getAllNotes(): Option<NonEmptyList<Note>> =
        NonEmptyList.fromList(noteRepository.findAll())

    override fun createNote(note: Option<Note>) : Note {
        note.map {
            kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC_NAME,  NoteEvent.Created(it))
        }
        return note.getOrElse { Note(id=0) }
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    override fun getNotesByAuthor(author: String): Option<NonEmptyList<Note>> {
        val noteList = noteRepository.findByAuthor(author)
        return NonEmptyList.fromList(noteList)
    }
}
```

My consumer

```
package com.remusrd.notesample.service

import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener
import org.springframework.messaging.Message
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class createdNotesConsumer {


    @KafkaListener(topics = ["notes"], groupId = "noteGroup")
    fun recieve(noteEvent: Message<Any>) {
        println("received" + noteEvent + noteEvent.javaClass)
    }
}
```

The entity

```
package com.remusrd.notesample.domain

import java.time.LocalDateTime
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "note")
data class Note(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long,
    val content: String = "",
    val creationDate: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
    val lastModified: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
    val author: String = ""
)
```

And my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = "1.3.10"
        springBootVersion = "2.1.1.RELEASE"
        springCloudVersion = "Greenwich.M3"
        arrow_version = "0.8.1"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin"
apply plugin: "kotlin-spring"
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
apply plugin: "kotlin-allopen"
apply plugin: "kotlin-noarg"
apply plugin: "kotlin-jpa"


group "com.remusrd"
version "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}
noArg{
    annotation("com.remusrd.notesample.domain.annotation.NoArg")
}
allOpen{
    annotation("com.remusrd.notesample.domain.annotation.Open")
}

dependencies {
    // Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin"
    implementation "io.arrow-kt:arrow-core:$arrow_version"
    implementation "io.arrow-kt:arrow-data:$arrow_version"

    // Spring Boot
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:$springBootVersion"
    implementation "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.7"



    // BBDD
    implementation "mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.13"
    implementation "com.h2database:h2:1.4.197"


    // Test
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

This is the trace I'm getting

```
2018-12-05 16:48:56.884 ERROR 8331 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler   : Error while processing: null

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition notes-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[123, 34, 110, 111, 116, 101, 34, 58, 123, 34, 105, 100, 34, 58, 48, 44, 34, 99, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 34, 58, 34, 72, 111, 108, 97, 32, 113, 117, -61, -87, 32, 116, 97, 108, 34, 44, 34, 99, 114, 101, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 68, 97, 116, 101, 34, 58, 34, 50, 48, 49, 56, 45, 49, 50, 45, 48, 53, 32, 49, 54, 58, 52, 53, 58, 53, 57, 34, 44, 34, 108, 97, 115, 116, 77, 111, 100, 105, 102, 105, 101, 100, 34, 58, 34, 50, 48, 49, 56, 45, 49, 50, 45, 48, 53, 32, 49, 54, 58, 52, 53, 58, 53, 57, 34, 44, 34, 97, 117, 116, 104, 111, 114, 34, 58, 34, 82, 105, 99, 104, 97, 114, 100, 34, 125, 125]] from topic [notes]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDateTime` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2018-12-05 16:45:59')
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"note":{"id":0,"content":"yo","creationDate":"2018-12-05 16:45:59","lastModified":"2018-12-05 16:45:59","author":"Richard"}}"; line: 1, column: 58] (through reference chain: com.remusrd.notesample.domain.event.NoteEvent$Modified["note"]->com.remusrd.notesample.domain.Note["creationDate"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1452) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1028) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:371) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:323) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1373) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:171) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:136) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:369) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:136) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:369) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1611) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1234) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:328) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1041) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3300(Fetcher.java:110) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1223) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1400(Fetcher.java:1072) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:562) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:523) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1230) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1187) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1154) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:719) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:676) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

Edit: https://github.com/RemusRD/notesample this is the repo, if you have any recommendations in order to improve the code just tell me

Edit2: Here is the new KafkaConfig

```
package com.remusrd.notesample.configuration

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
import org.springframework.kafka.core.*
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer


@Configuration
class KafkaConfig {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder: Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
    @Autowired
    lateinit var kafkaProperties: KafkaProperties


    @Bean
    fun kafkaTemplate(): KafkaTemplate<Any, Any> {
        return KafkaTemplate<Any, Any>(defaultKafkaProducerFactory())
    }


    @Bean
    fun defaultKafkaConsumerFactory(): ConsumerFactory<Any, Any> {
        val objectMapper = jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build() as ObjectMapper
        val jsonDeserializer = JsonDeserializer<Any>(objectMapper)
        jsonDeserializer.configure(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(), false)
        val kafkaConsumerFactory = DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Any, Any>(
            kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(),
            jsonDeserializer,
            jsonDeserializer
        )
        kafkaConsumerFactory.setValueDeserializer(jsonDeserializer)
        return kafkaConsumerFactory
    }

    @Bean
    fun defaultKafkaProducerFactory(): ProducerFactory<Any, Any> {
        val jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer<Any>(jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build())
        jsonSerializer.configure(kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties(), false)
        val factory = DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Any, Any>(
            kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties(),
            jsonSerializer,
            jsonSerializer
        )
        val transactionIdPrefix = kafkaProperties.producer
            .transactionIdPrefix
        if (transactionIdPrefix != null) {
            factory.setTransactionIdPrefix(transactionIdPrefix)
        }
        return factory
    }
}
```

Comment: May you can share some simple Spring Boot project on GitHub to let us to play with and reproduce? Looking to the code so far, I don't see any issues. The `kafkaConsumerFactory` overrides one auto-configured in the `KafkaAutoConfiguration`, so a `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` should accept your one with the `JavaTimeModule` for deserialization. Not clear what can cause to use a default `JsonDeserializer`. I can suggest to remove the `spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer` property though, but not sure how that may cause override. So, the project to investigate would be helpful.

Comment: After making your simple project working, that would be great to ask you for the contribution to our Spring for Apache Kafka samples: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/tree/master/samples

Comment: @ArtemBilan Sure!, No problem with that.
Edit: I just added the repo to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem that you populate your customized `JsonDeserializer` into the `keyDeserializer` on the `ConsumerFactory`:

```
@Bean
fun defaultKafkaConsumerFactory(): ConsumerFactory<Any, Any> {
    val objectMapper = jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build() as ObjectMapper
    objectMapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
    val jsonDeserializer = JsonDeserializer<Any>(objectMapper)
    jsonDeserializer.configure(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(), false)
    val kafkaConsumerFactory = DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Any, Any>(
        kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties()
    )
    kafkaConsumerFactory.setKeyDeserializer(jsonDeserializer)
    return kafkaConsumerFactory
}
```

Use `setValueDeserializer()` or just remove this one in favor of that `kafkaConsumerFactory`.

Fully not sure why do you have a pair of `ConsumerFactory` and `ProducerFactory`...

Comment: Great! made it work. 

One of the problems was the one that you mentioned, I also removed one of each consumer and producer beans(I am editing the post in order to add it)

Also, the DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE was unnecessary.

I have few more questions if you dont mind.

1. Is it correct to configure the factories as <Object, Object>?

2. Is it fine to have the same deserialiser for both consumerFactory and producerFactory?

Comment: 1. Yes, that’s fine. The target listener can be any type to expect as long as you deal with JSON. 2. No, that’s related. Producer needs `serializer`, but consumer- `deserializer`. They are different objects. However you can use the same `ObjectMapper` for both of them

Comment: Thanks, you are super helpful, I would like to ask one more question, It is a little unrelated but I have been not able to find info about it, maybe I should open another question on SO.

The question is: When and who should create/send the events in a microservice architecture? I guess it depends on the context, but, in a simple spring boot app, should it be created in the service layer? I mean, should I call the repository to persist and produce the event?

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a new SO question  with more info to determine your issue.